# Can we apply the /32 subnet to the address 200.200.200.234?

Tags: subnet, linux

Is the `/32` subnet only for loopback addresses? Can we have the subnet for the non-loopback addresses>

I get the following error, when I am trying to delete the route with a `/32` subnet:

```
 ip route del 200.200.200.234/255.255.255.255 -

Netlink error(code 3)
```

Comment: Does that route exist?

Comment: Does `ip` on Linux even support this subnet mask notation? Shouldn't it be `ip route del 200.200.200.234/32` ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A `/32` network must be routed since there is no default gateway for a device on it to use to get to addresses off the network (every other address).

In some cases you may see a route like this which is also contained in another route in the routing table. For instance, Cisco routers with later IOS versions will show a `/32` route for the actual interface addresses using an `L`, but the network route will show with a `C`.

In this example, the `L` route is the address applied to `interface GigabitEthernet0/1`, while the `C` route is the network connected to that interface.

```
R1#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

      128.190.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        128.190.32.0/19 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
L        128.190.34.204/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
```